Как сделать так, чтобы джоба Gitlab CI срабатывала после мерджа ветки в мастер?
Разбираюсь с CI/CD в гитлабе и пытаюсь настроить простой пайплайн, который будет запускаться только после слияния MR в мастер. Но не могу понять как это можно сделать.
Я сделал вот такие правила:
job:
  rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
    when: on_success
  - when: never

Но джоба срабатывает просто при пушах в MR. А как сделать так, чтобы при пушах ничего не происходило, а пайплайн запускался только после нажатия на кнопку слияния MR в мастер, после того как кто-либо зааппрувит MR?

- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"

